# ruby send method passing multiple parameters

Tags: ruby

Trying to create objects and call methods dynamically by

```
Object.const_get(class_name).new.send(method_name,parameters_array)
```

which is working fine when

```
Object.const_get(RandomClass).new.send(i_take_arguments,[10.0])
```

but throwing wrong number of arguments 1 for 2 for

```
Object.const_get(RandomClass).new.send(i_take_multiple_arguments,[25.0,26.0])
```

The Random Class defined is

```
class RandomClass
def i_am_method_one
    puts "I am method 1"
end
def i_take_arguments(a)
    puts "the argument passed is #{a}"
end
def i_take_multiple_arguments(b,c)
    puts "the arguments passed are #{b} and #{c}"
end
    end
```

Can someone help me on how to send mutiple parameters to a ruby method dynamically

Answer (score 278, accepted):

```
send("i_take_multiple_arguments", *[25.0,26.0]) #Where star is the "splat" operator
```

or

```
send(:i_take_multiple_arguments, 25.0, 26.0)
```

Comment: Might be worth noting that the `*` in this context is the "splat" operator.

Answer (score 14):

You can alternately call `send` with it's synonym `__send__`:

```
r = RandomClass.new
r.__send__(:i_take_multiple_arguments, 'a_param', 'b_param')
```

By the way* you can pass hashes as params comma separated like so:

```
imaginary_object.__send__(:find, :city => "city100")
```

or new hash syntax:

```
imaginary_object.__send__(:find, city: "city100", loc: [-76, 39])
```

According to Black, `__send__` is safer to namespace.

> “Sending is a broad concept: email is sent, data gets sent to I/O sockets, and so forth. It’s not uncommon for programs to define a method called send that conflicts with Ruby’s built-in send method. Therefore, Ruby gives you an alternative way to call send: `__send__`. By convention, no one ever writes a method with that name, so the built-in Ruby version is always available and never comes into conflict with newly written methods. It looks strange, but it’s safer than the plain send version from the point of view of method-name clashes”

Black also suggests wrapping calls to `__send__` in `if respond_to?(method_name)`.

```
if r.respond_to?(method_name)
    puts r.__send__(method_name)
else
    puts "#{r.to_s} doesn't respond to #{method_name}"
end
```

Ref: Black, David A. The well-grounded Rubyist. Manning, 2009. P.171.

*I came here looking for hash syntax for `__send__`, so may be useful for other googlers. ;)